# Mandelbrot set rotation JS

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, fractals, mandelbrot

There is a simple JS code that renders a very basic Mandelbrot fractal.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
  canvasWidth = canvas.width,
  canvasHeight = canvas.height,
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const maxIterations = 100,
  magnificationFactor = 200,
  panX = 2,
  panY = 1.25;

let drawPoint = (x, y, color) => {
  var pointSize = 1;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}

let mandelbrot = (c, z = 0) => z ^ 2 + c;

let BelongsToMandelbrotSet = (x, y) => {
  let realComponentOfResult = x,
    imaginaryComponentOfResult = y;

  for (let i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {

    let tempRealComponent = realComponentOfResult * realComponentOfResult - imaginaryComponentOfResult * imaginaryComponentOfResult + x,
      tempImaginaryComponent = 2 * realComponentOfResult * imaginaryComponentOfResult + y;

    realComponentOfResult = tempRealComponent;
    imaginaryComponentOfResult = tempImaginaryComponent;
  }

  if (realComponentOfResult * imaginaryComponentOfResult < 5)
    return true;

  return false;
}

for (let x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < canvasHeight; y++) {

    let belongsToSet =
      BelongsToMandelbrotSet(x / magnificationFactor - panX,
        y / magnificationFactor - panY);
    if (belongsToSet)
      drawPoint(x, y, '#000')

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

The task is to rotate this fractal by the random angle along its axis.
And it shouldn't be a canvas rotation or its image data, but I have to tweak the initial fractal formula to do that.

For example, if the angle is 45 degrees or PI / 4 in radians, the output should look like

[image]

I have tried to play with `x = center.x + 500 * Math.cos(theta), y = center.y + 500 * Math.sin(theta)` without any success.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to transform the coordinates right in the main loop, where you do scaling and translation:

```
 let x1 = x * Math.cos(theta) - y * Math.sin(theta)
 let y1 = x * Math.sin(theta) + y * Math.cos(theta)

 let belongsToSet = BelongsToMandelbrotSet(x1/magnificationFactor - panX, ...
 ...drawPoint(x, y, '#000')
```

To further simplify this, create an [affine transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) for all kinds of transforms and apply it once.